# Where should I do the text formatting for items in my recylerview adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, text-formatting

I have multiple values available that needs be shown in different item in a adapter. For e.g there is total items, new items, source and posted by but these values will be shown in different style like new/total and many other formatting like Total: 35.
So my question is how and where should I do the formatting:

1. Do it in the adapter and for each item I can format the text and set it
2. Do it once and save it in the DB, so that the formatting is done once
   The only concern in second is extra data is stored in DB that is of no use to api or app. It is just for optimization.

Please suggest the best approach out of these two or if any other better approach please post your answer with it.

Comment: What do you mean store in the DB? That costs additional storage and disk R/W. My 'vote" goes for option 1

Comment: Your question is confused. If you are talking about rendering UI, most of the people will definitely assign this job to the ViewHolder class. And this class will be called in the adapter. But if you are talking about saving the style in dynamic or static way and other optimization. This can be discussed.

Comment: @cricket_007 Storing in DB means I will do the required formating and will save it in DB for the Adapter use to avoid formatting in Adapter

Comment: @LongRanger Please see above comment and revert if any other clarification required

Comment: Do you mean you will get the View formatted(such as text size, color, background)  every time you get it from DB ? And no extra formatting in Adapter?

Comment: Databases stores single lines of text. Certainly your view is not as simple as that. Otherwise, you have a third option. Implement the string formatting with `toString` for the list objects

Comment: You can also save the ViewConfig information in json format and save it in db. This will be flexible to do your config.

Comment: as @cricket_007 says, option 2 cost you additional storage and disk R/w. Use option 1. You should save the 'raw' data in the database and do the formatting in Adapter. This will save you from a headache later when you need to change the style. Save data in the database and make the data as flexible as you can so whenever you need some changes, you only have to do a minimum effort.

Comment: my concern is, if i do these formatting in adapter it will happen on every scroll and that can make it slow on low end devices.

Comment: I don't think you understand how RecyclerView works... The formatting only happens once, when a view is within the screen bounds, and then is cached, or "recycled" via the ViewHolder

Comment: @cricket_007 I think I have the understanding of how RecyclerView works :) and it actually holds the view for you and don't let you go through the findviewbyid hierarchy. So the views are created once but the text to be set in those views will be formatted on scroll. Please correct me if am wrong because if it doesn't RecyclerView has to maintain state of each tuple and it will be a mess. It is reusing the view not the data inside it.

Comment: I have not read anywhere that "caching" some ViewConfig object yields better performance than just applying the styling at runtime. That is my main point

Comment: That's what m asking will it make much difference if I do these String.format things prior and save it in db and just show them as it is when showing in adapter or simply do this in onbindviewholder?